# Why is tryCatch not deterministic?

Tags: r, try-catch

Suppose I have the following function:

```
is.valid.timezone <- function(timezone) {
  #test the timezones are valid
  tryCatch(
    {
      strptime('2019-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d", tz=timezone)
      return(T)
    },
    warning=function(w) {
      return(F)
    }, 
    error=function(e) {
      return(F)
    })
```

I then try it out. Every time it runs, it gives me a different result. Take for example the following scenarios:

```
> is.valid.timezone("America")
[1] TRUE
> is.valid.timezone("Americas")
[1] FALSE
> is.valid.timezone("Americas")
[1] TRUE
```

**All of these should be `FALSE`**. It seems it can't make up its mind for "Americas" because it returns BOTH TRUE and FALSE which **should be impossible** because given the same input I should see the same output.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0 tools_3.6.0
```

Comment: I get for all a `TRUE` (3.6.2)

Comment: I have `FALSE` only during the first run. Maybe you can check that `timezone` is in `OlsonNames()` instead

Comment: That is a great idea to use `OlsonNames()`. Never knew about that... but just curious why this `tryCatch` doesn't work as expected...

Comment: tz: Invalid values are most commonly treated as UTC, *on some platforms* with a warning.

Comment: @GKi - that's what I am banking on and hence the reason for catching the warning and returning `FALSE`

Comment: When I use your code and then I run `strptime('2019-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d", tz="EST")` I get a warning `In strptime("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "EST") :
  unknown timezone 'Americas'`. It looks like somehow evaluation is getting broken. I suspect this is a bug.

Comment: It looks like that `strptime` gives on *some platforms* a warning for *some* invalid `tz` values *only for the first time*.  `tryCatch` is working deterministic. It simply does not get a warning from `strptime`. Maybe use `"America" %in% OlsonNames()` instead.